# Calculator function returns NaN when computing value of numbers using PEMDAS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a calculator following PEMDAS operations.

When I input these numbers into my function `3*7+2-1*4` I expect my function to return 19. However, my function returns `NaN`

This is the function I have written:

```
let test = '3*7+2-1*4'
let signMap = {};
const availSigns = []
const signs = ['*','+','-','/','√']
let vals = test.split(/[*√+/-]/);
for(let i = 0; i < test.split('').length; i++){
    if(signs.includes(test[i])){
        availSigns.push(test[i])
        signMap[test[i]] = signMap[test[i]] ? signMap[test[i]] + 1 : 1
    } else {
    }
}
let tempRes = 0
vals = vals.filter(item => item !== '')
console.log('starting', vals)
while(vals.length > 1){
    console.log('beginning while', vals)
    if(signMap['√'] > 0){
        let pos = parseFloat(availSigns.indexOf('√'))
        tempRes = Math.sqrt(parseFloat(vals[pos]))
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        vals[pos] = tempRes
        signMap['√'] --
    }
    if(signMap['*'] > 0){
        let pos = parseFloat(availSigns.indexOf('*'))
        tempRes = parseFloat(vals[pos]) * parseFloat(vals[pos+1])
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        vals[pos] = tempRes
        vals.splice(pos+1, 1)
        signMap['*'] --
        console.log(`* ${vals} sM:${JSON.stringify(signMap)}`)
    } if(signMap['/'] > 0){
        let pos = parseFloat(availSigns.indexOf('/'))
        tempRes = parseFloat(vals[pos]) / parseFloat(vals[pos+1])
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        vals[pos] = tempRes
        vals.splice(pos+1, 1)
        signMap['/'] --
        console.log('/', vals)
    } if(signMap['+'] > 0){
        let pos = parseFloat(availSigns.indexOf('+'))
        tempRes = parseFloat(vals[pos]) + parseFloat(vals[pos+1])
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        vals[pos] = tempRes
        vals.splice(pos+1, 1)
        signMap['+'] --
        console.log(`+ ${vals} sM:${JSON.stringify(signMap)}`)
    } if(signMap['-'] > 0){
        let pos = parseFloat(availSigns.indexOf('-'))
        tempRes = parseFloat(vals[pos]) - parseFloat(vals[pos+1])
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        vals[pos] = tempRes
        vals.splice(pos+1, 1)
        signMap['-'] --
        availSigns.splice(pos, 1)
        console.log(`- ${vals} sM:${JSON.stringify(signMap)}, ind:${pos}`)
    }
}
console.log('res', tempRes)
```

These are the console.logs my function returns:

```
starting [ '3', '7', '2', '1', '4' ]
beginning while [ '3', '7', '2', '1', '4' ]
* 21,2,1,4 sM:{"*":1,"+":1,"-":1}
+ 23,1,4 sM:{"*":1,"+":0,"-":1}
- 22,4 sM:{"*":1,"+":0,"-":0}, ind:0
beginning while [ 22, '4' ]
* 4 sM:{"*":0,"+":0,"-":0}
res NaN
```

Any ideas on how I can better improve my function to make it work

Comment: In the second time the `if(signMap['*'] > 0)` succeeds in the while loop, there is no value in `availSigns` with `"*"` (`availSigns.indexOf('*')`). This returns `-1`, which when you take the square root of its value is NaN.

Comment: @code not sure I'm fully getting this, mind adding as an answer?

Comment: So when `indexOf` doesn't find the element in your array, it will return `-1`. You're trying to take the square root of -1, which is _`i`_. JS doesn't know imaginary numbers and simply returns NaN. There appears to be some logical bug where even when `signMap['*'] > 0` there is not `'*'` in your `availSigns` array.

Comment: @code I am not using square root for this calculation. This is what I am computing `let test = '3*7+2-1*4'
`

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the square root case :P. What's actually happening is the `indexOf` is returning `-1` (which you assigned to `pos`), then you're trying to access `vals[pos]`, which is `undefined`. Multiplying that to `vals[pos + 1]` (`vals[0]`) will give `NaN`.